# NPM fix the warning

Tags: node.js, npm, warnings

I do not understand how to fix the warnings. any idea? Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference to `fs`inside your `package.json` file which is not needed because `fs`is a part of node's core library.

Remove the entry from `package.json` and message will disappear.

Comment: Hmm try to remove the entire node_modules folder and run npm install -l again. What happens then?

Comment: installation is successful except this warning:
npm WARN deprecated set-immediate@0.1.1: Use `setimmediate` instead

Comment: It's a different issue but reading solves it. There's a new version of set-imediate which is located at a different npm url. Old one is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-immediate. New one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/setimmediate so remove the - char from package.json and it's fixed again.